# Python manage.py runserver command not working and error message not specific

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I just started learning Django this day and I got stuck because when I ran python manage.py runserver it gave this message....
I've tried python manage.py migrate still nothing.
I've waited an hour to see if it makes a difference and it doesn't. It seems stupid but I've been stuck here for a while.

I have activated virtual environments and added python to Path ... I don't know what went wrong.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Python'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\mysite\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\owner\mysite\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 343, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 232, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 226, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Python'```
````

Comment: Please post the code that led to that error. And as little of it as possible -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where and how do you execute the command?

Comment: I executed the command at the terminal. "Python manage.py runserver"

Comment: Could you run that command again and copy the complete output? I find it hard to believe that the traceback ends with `No module named "C:\\Python\`\`\``

Comment: I've edited the traceback on the question it actually ends with No module named 'C:\\Python'